# how to copy string (e.g., pwd) to PRIMARY in matlab?

Tags: matlab, terminal

it is known that using **paste** can copy string to CLIPBOARD.

```
paste('copy',pwd)
```

But how to copy strings to PRIMARY in linux so that a middle key is sufficient to paste it to other terminals?

Thanks

**UPDATES**

it is found that once using matlab command line mode in bash by :

```
matlab -nodesktop
```

the kill (ctrl+k) and yank (ctrl+y) is not working, specifically, the input syntax at the prompt can be killed by ctrl+k while can not yanked back by ctrl+y. perhaps understanding how to paste string to PRIMARY can also resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you mean you want to programatically copy text into the UNIX clipboard, say at the end of a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is "how to copy strings to PRIMARY in linux so that a middle [mouse] key is sufficient to paste it to other terminals?".

Thomas Dickey pointed you in the right direction with that xclip. You write that you need more details.

Here are these details in the form of some matlab code. Suppose you want to place the string "Example String" into the primary X11 selection:

```
data = 'Example String';
system(['echo "' data '" | xclip -selection primary']);
```

You can now paste "Example String" into any other terminal on the same X11 display using the middle mouse button.

Using echo here to deliver your string to xclip is just the quickest way to demonstrate working code. If your string contains characters special to the shell, or if users can specify the content of that string, you should not use it like this, but rather save your string to a file and then invoke

```
system('xclip -selection primary filename_where_you_saved_the_string');
```

You need to install xclip for this method to work. xclip talks to the xserver for you. Specifically, when you start it, it tells the xserver that it has the primary selection. Then, when some other xclient wants to access the content of the primary selection, it responds the these enquiries. Finally, it exits when another xclient aquires the primary selection. Until then, it conveniently runs in the background, so that it does not block your matlab code.

Note that xclip is not your only option. You could also interact with the xserver selections from within a mex file. But this would be way too complicated when a working tool like xclip already exists.

In your Update section of the question you express hope that understanding how to set the X11 primary selection programmatically with matlab, might help you achieve better keyboard-based command line editing in matlab -nodesktop mode, especially with respect to cutting the part of the command line to the right of the cursor and pasting that part later somewhere else.

I am sorry to tell you that the new understanding does not help here. In -nodesktop mode, matlab interactive command line editing does not interact with the xserver selections at all. Only the containing terminal emulators do. Mathworks would have to fix the command line editing in -nodesktop mode, but I doubt they would want to invest effort into this hardly used user interface mode. Nevertheless, if I were you and wanted this possibility, I would file a bug with mathworks requesting a "yank" keyboard shortcut for -nodesktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

The [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) program can do this (if not already installed, you may be able to install it, since there are packages for the usual systems such as Debian and Fedora):

> Reads from standard in, or from one or more files, and makes the data available as an X selection for pasting into X applications. Prints current X selection to standard out.

For discussion:

- [Copy file to xclip and paste to Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22494/copy-file-to-xclip-and-paste-to-firefox)
- [Command-Line Copy&Paste With xclip (Debian/Ubuntu)](https://www.howtoforge.com/command-line-copy-and-paste-with-xclip-debian-ubuntu)
- [Copy Shell Prompt Output To Linux / UNIX X Clipboard Directly](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

If you run matlab in a BASH shell with the `--nodesktop`, then it will behave like any BASH shell.

On my gnome-shell box, highlighting text will place it into the UNIX clipboard and be pasted with middle mouse button.  This should work in most windows.

To copy text into your desktop's clipboard (like gnome-shell), one has to know the shortcut for the teriminal window they are using.  For `gnome-terminal`, the default is `CTRL+SHIFT+C', I believe you can configure you're own shortcut.

To paste from your desktop's clipboard, the default for `gnome-terminal` is `CTRL+SHIFT+V`.